# Calculate time duration using awk

Tags: awk

How to calculate time duration by using awk for the following file:

```
02 0F 00 80 C9 CD AB 00 00 48 CF 00 00 00 00 00 00 6B E7 01 07 1A 16 1B 36 00  with Timestamp2014-03-12 18:46:59.986000
02 0F 00 80 CA CD AB 00 00 48 CF 00 00 00 00 00 00 6B E7 01 07 1A 14 DB 39 00  with Timestamp2014-03-12 18:47:02.446279
02 13 23 C8 B0 CD AB 00 00 FF FF E2 75 AC 21 4E 83 00 00 01 83 6C E7 01 11 1A 36 DD 39 00  with Timestamp2014-03-12 18:47:02.455278
02 03 12 00 B0 6B E7 01 03 1A FF FF FF FF  with Timestamp2014-03-12 18:47:02.457279
02 17 00 80 CB CD AB 00 00 48 CF 00 10 E2 75 AC 21 4E 83 00 00 00 00 00 00 6B E6 01 07 1A 10 9B 3D 00  with Timestamp2014-03-12 18:47:06.196279
02 10 63 C8 B1 CD AB 00 00 E2 75 AC 21 4E 83 00 00 04 6A E6 01 0F 1A 14 9D 3D 00  with Timestamp2014-03-12 18:47:06.205278
02 03 12 00 B1 6C E6 01 03 1A FF FF FF FF  with Timestamp2014-03-12 18:47:06.206279
```

In other words, last line timestamp value minus first line timestamp values.

Comment: What would be your desired result?

Comment: Thanks for replying to me. The desired result is the time duration of all packets for example the first time stamp is 18:46:59.986000 and the last one is 18:47:06.206279  so the time will be the 1+2+....+last= time in millisecond.

Comment: While this could be done in `awk`, I'm guessing that `python` or `perl` or something else that has date/time parsing functionality built in would definitely be a better bet...

Comment: Many thanks. Can you help me in this as you suggest. Regards

Comment: GNU awk has it's own date/time functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want (using GNU awk for `mktime()`)?

```
$ cat tst.awk
sub(/.*Timestamp/,"") {
    split($0,t,/[-:. ]/)
    time[++nr] = mktime(t[1]" "t[2]" "t[3]" "t[4]" "t[5]" "t[6]) "." t[7]
}
END { print time[nr] - time[1] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
6.22028
```

Comment: Many thanks but I need it to be within scripting file if possible to be like this for example `BEGIN {

duration =0


} 

{ 


if ( condition) { 

duration computation 

     }

}

END { 

    
    printf "Time duration:” duration "\n" 


}`

Comment: the script will be stated by `#!/usr/bin/gawk -f`

Comment: I've done this but the final result is zero as well can any one help me please  `if (sub(/.*Timestamp/,"")) {
    split($0,t,/[-:. ]/)
    time[NR] = mktime(t[1]" "t[2]" "t[3]" "t[4]" "t[5]" "t[6]) "." t[7]
}`

Comment: You probably have blank lines at the start and end of your input file or it doesn't match your posted sample input in some other way. The scripts not complicated - just add some debugging prints to the script and figure it out.

Comment: And it's not causing your problem but in general don't use a shebang to execute your script, just call it as `gawk 'script' "$@"`.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton, can you just give an idea what you've done as I am not familiar with awk and gawk. Thanks in advance!

Comment: removed everything up to Timestamp on each line, split the remaining text on any of the chars listed into an array, constructed a seconds-since-the-epoch timestamp from the result and store that in an array indexed by line number, and then once all lines are read subtract the timestamp for the first line from the timestamp for the last line.

Comment: Many thanks @Ed Morton, but what if we have 300 lines?

Comment: it will work as-is. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @Ed Morton; it is not working with this example:

```
Number of saved packets= 373
Protocol: IEEE 802.15.4
Packet #0 :02 0F 00 80 C9 CD AB 00 00 48 CF 00 00 00 00 00 00 6B E7 01 07 1A 16 1B 36 00  with Timestamp2014-03-12 18:46:59.986000
###################################################################################

Packet #1 :02 0F 00 80 CA CD AB 00 00 48 CF 00 00 00 00 00 00 6B E7 01 07 1A 14 DB 39 00  with Timestamp2014-03-12 18:47:02.446279
###################################################################################

Packet #2 :02 13 23 C8 B0 CD AB 00 00 FF FF E2 75 AC 21 4E 83 00 00 01 83 6C E7 01 11 1A 36 DD 39 00  with Timestamp2014-03-12 18:47:02.455278
###################################################################################

Packet #3 :02 03 12 00 B0 6B E7 01 03 1A FF FF FF FF  with Timestamp2014-03-12 18:47:02.457279
###################################################################################

Packet #4 :02 17 00 80 CB CD AB 00 00 48 CF 00 10 E2 75 AC 21 4E 83 00 00 00 00 00 00 6B E6 01 07 1A 10 9B 3D 00  with Timestamp2014-03-12 18:47:06.196279
###################################################################################

Packet #5 :02 10 63 C8 B1 CD AB 00 00 E2 75 AC 21 4E 83 00 00 04 6A E6 01 0F 1A 14 9D 3D 00  with Timestamp2014-03-12 18:47:06.205278
###################################################################################

Packet #6 :02 03 12 00 B1 6C E6 01 03 1A FF FF FF FF  with Timestamp2014-03-12 18:47:06.206279
```

Comment: Well, no it wouldn't because that sample doesn't fit the pattern of the sample you originally posted and what you stated you wanted which was the last line compared to the FIRST LINE. I updated my answer to work with the new format.

Comment: Thank you so much it works now. all the best